# IE doesn't download file with jQuery File Download plugin

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, controller

I’m using  jQuery File Download plugin in my java code and work fine with Firefox and Chrome but doesn’t start the download with Internet Explorer.
I set these headers:

```
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+file);
```

and in my javascript I use this code:

```
$.fileDownload(
    "/async/paas/caaas/downloadCertificate/"+serialNumber, 
    {
        successCallback: function (url) {
            //
        },
        failCallback: function (HttpServletResponse, url) {
            $(“#modalDownloadFailedCertificate”).modal("show");
        }
    }
);
return false;
```

In IE, with F12 modality, i have this row:

URL: async/paas/caaas/downloadCertificate/591C94
Metodo: GET (In sospeso...)
Risultato: (In sospeso...)
Tipo:   (In sospeso...)
Ricevuti: 0 B
Tempo impiegato: (In sospeso...)
Iniziatore: esplorazione frame

Someone has the same problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding this line before response.setHeader:

```
response.reset();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using spring security version 4 or later?

jquery filedownload internally uses an iframe.

Spring security In version 4, x-frame-options is set to 'DENY' to block iframes for security reasons.

So to use jquery filedownload you have to change the option value to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:headers>
        <security:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
    </security:headers>
    ..........
</security:http>
```

Add settings to the security context file

I wish you well.